# How to open wordpress submenus on click and remain open after page load?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to open WordPress sub menus on click and remains open even on page load? I want it to open permanently after click. I am using which opens menus on click and it closes when I go to another page. Please check the code below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.top-menus ul.sub-menu').hide();
$('.top-menus > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");
$('.top-menus > ul > li > a').click(function () {

var checkElement = $(this).next();

$('.top-menus li').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal');
}

if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('.top-menus ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
}

if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
});
});
</script>


<div class="top-menus">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Menu1</a>
 <ul classs="submenu">
 <li><a href-"">submneu1</a></li>
 <li><a href-"">submneu2</a></li>
 <li><a href-"">submneu3</a></li>
</ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it always open for any pages once opened?

Comment: @Bhautik Actually I have a sub-menu for 2 -3 parent items so I want something like once the submenu is open it remains open

Comment: Yes but id does open to every page?